# PHP utf8 encoding with array

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a array of ASCII encoded email into utf-8 or plaintext format or readable.
I tried to use utf8_encode($str); to encode, but its not working with array.
Here is my code (php).

```
foreach ($datas as $values) {
    echo utf8_encode($values)."<br/>";
}
```

Here is the array.

```
Array (
[0] => \0E\0-\0m\0a\0i\0l\0 \01\0 \0-\0 \0V\0a\0l\0u\0e\0
[1] => \0v\0a\0r\0a\0d\0a\0l\0a\0k\0s\0h\0m\0i\01\02\03\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0
[2] => \0s\0a\0l\0v\0i\0n\0w\0i\0l\0s\0o\0n\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0
[3] => \0s\0h\0e\0m\0e\0e\0m\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0
)
```

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. No need to convert: it is already UTF-8.

Comment: And what does `$datas` contain?

Comment: $datas contain the array i gave in question.

Comment: The output i'm getting is `\0v\0a\0r\0a\0d\0a\0l\0a\0k\0s\0h\0m\0i\01\02\03\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0
\0s\0a\0l\0v\0i\0n\0w\0i\0l\0s\0o\0n\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0
\0s\0h\0e\0m\0e\0e\0m\0@\0g\0m\0a\0i\0l\0.\0c\0o\0m\0` i need the output like example@example.com (email format).

Answer (score 1):

Make a brutal

```
foreach ($datas as $values) {
    echo str_replace('\\0', '', $values)."<br/>";
}
```

<sup>However, where did you get this data?</sup>

Comment: Google Contacts CSV export.